# Java split and throw away on repeated char using regex

Tags: java, regex, split, repeat

I'm really struggling with regex right now...

I've read up and looked at a lot of examples, but cannot seem to find the answer. I'd like to split a string when the string "::" is found, and I would like to discard those two characters. The closest I have gotten was splitting on the correct pattern, but it kept the colons. Here is an example of my input and desired output:

```
String input = "One::Two::Three";
```

I would like the output to be:

```
output[0]: "One"
output[1]: "Two"
output[2]: "Three"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `String#split()` method which takes a separator string as argument and outputs the divided string to an array. Note that the argument can be a regular expression.

```
String input = "One::Two::Three";
String[] output = input.split("::");

System.out.println(output[0]); // One
System.out.println(output[1]); // Two
System.out.println(output[2]); // Three
```

Here's the official documentation for [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Wow, so sorry! I cannot believe I did not try that. I thought I had to either put in a regex pattern or a single character. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
String input = "One::Two::Three";
String[] output = input.split("::");
for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {  
    System.out.println(output[i]);  
}
```